# Interpreting notation for a differential equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I'm looking at the following differential equation (see Appendix B of the [following paper](http://www.nbi.dk/~hertz/nscourse/amit97CC.pdf)):

$$
\partial_t\mu[V_E]=-\mu[V_E] + C_{EE}[x\nu_E+(1-x)v_{ext}]-C_{EI}J_{EI}\nu_I,
$$

where $\mu[V_E]$ is the mean of $V_E$.

This equation is described as "the evolution of the moment $\mu[V_E]$."

My question is, how exactly should I interpret this?  Is it simply the derivative of $\mu[V_E]$ with respect to $t$?  But $\partial$ is the symbol for a partial derivative.  So should I evaluate this differently than I would $d_t\mu[V_E]$ (assuming the latter is something that even makes sense)?  What are some strategies I might use to solve this equation?

Some things to note: In this equation, $C_{EE}, x, C_{EI}, J_{EI},$ and $\nu_{ext}$ are constants.  $\nu_E$ and $\nu_I$ (I think?) are variables.

I can provide more content-specific information on request.  My main concern is getting clear on the notation.

**EDIT**: I'm not sure whether this is helpful or not, but earlier in the paper, the following definition is given:

$$
\mu_E=C_{EE}J_{EE}[x\nu_E\tau_E+(1-x)\nu_{ext}\tau_E]-C_{EI}J_{EI}\nu_I\tau_E.
$$

I say it might not be helpful only because I'm not quite sure whether $\mu_E$ is the same thing as $\mu[V_E]$ (though they're definitely related).  Note that the differential equation above is very similar to this equation -- but with, e.g., $J_{EE}$ and $\tau_E$ removed.

Comment: What paper? $\; \;$

Comment: amit & brunel, '97, cereb cortex -- a PDF can be found on google scholar even without a journal subscription.

Comment: @Raskolnikov if you read it you'll see $\mu_E$ is the mean of the afferent input, whereas $\mu[V_E]$ is the mean of the membrane potential.  but i don't think it's ever stated explicitly how to convert one to the other (or whether you can).  anyway, i'm not sure that distinction is important for my question.